# Mystery URL http://#/ Listed in XML Sitemap Created by WordPress SEO by Yoast Plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, google-xml-sitemaps

I'm using the Wordpress SEO by Yoast plugin. I'm having problems getting the Sitemaps XML section to work properly. Google gives me the dreaded red X for the status of the sitemap.

The error message Google gives is: 208 "Invalid URL
This is not a valid URL. Please correct it and resubmit."

The incorrect Google XML lists is: http://#/ . In the XML sitempap created by the plugin, I can see that that URL is listed.

I'm not sure where the XML Sitemap generator came up with this URL. In order to get my dropdown menus to work, I set the URL to # on some blank pages that only have a title.

For example, the first child in my navigation is a blank page with a URL set to # and a title of "A-C". The "A-C" page's children are the pages of all of the areas starting with A thru C. I set the "A-C" page's robot meta to noindex, nofollow. Does that have something to do with the problem?

I don't have a page named http://#/. As I don't have a page with this URL listed in my WordPress Pages section, I can't set it to noindex, nofollow. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up using the Google XML Sitemap plugin. You can input the post id's of the pages you want excluded from the sitemap. I excluded the pages with null links and now Google accepts the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The # was caused by the plugin "Page Links To" for me. This is a plugin that makes certain top level navigation link so that nothing happens when you click it and you have to choose a subcategory.

With Yoast SEO, you need to edit each page using # as a redirect under Advanced settings to "Never Include" in Sitemap. I also chose No Follow and No Index just in case. This then deleted the # link in my sitemap and when resubmitted to google, was accepted.